# How to identify the behaviour of a callback function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

The following are two examples -

```js
function someFunc(a){
    return a**2;
}

function calling(value,f){
    return f(value)+2;
}

calling(3,someFunc);
```

and

```js
const message = function() {  
    console.log("This message is shown after 3 seconds");
}
 
setTimeout(message, 3000);
```

In the first example, `someFunc` is executed first for the `calling` function to return a value; while in the second example, the program execution is paused for 3 seconds before the `message` function is called.

Is the function `someFunc` in the first example a callback function?
Also, how is the `message` function in the next example not executed prior to the timeout? Any answer would greatly help.

Answer (score 2):

> In the first example, someFunc is executed first for the calling function to return a value

No, it isn't.

`calling` is executed and `someFunc` is passed to it as an argument.

`calling` then calls `someFunc` (which was copied into `f`).

**Then** `calling` returns a value.

> while in the second example, the program execution is paused for 3 seconds before the message function is called.

No, it isn't.

`setTimeout` puts `message` on a queue with a note that it shouldn't be executed for at least three seconds.

The program then continues. It doesn't do anything because there is nothing for it to do, but it isn't paused.

> Is the function someFunc in the first example a callback function?

Yes

> Also, how is the message function in the next example not executed prior to the timeout?

Because mentioning the name of a variable holding a function doesn't call the function.

You need to do something to call it, such as using `()`.